# search for the directory locations with os.walk (and not to check the other directories the same level)

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I'm going to fetch all the filenames and locations in the particular sub directory (if fit the pattern). These sub directories are located in the different locations with different depth (as it was discussed: [how to get all the files from multiple folders with the same names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011734/how-to-get-all-the-files-from-multiple-folders-with-the-same-names/54012093#54012093)).

My problem: asap I find 'xyz' in the directory , I don't want to check if 'xyz' is a sub directory for any other directories on the same level (for an example, I don't want to check if 'D:/qwer/lkj' may contain 'xyz'.

```
D:/qwer/xyz
D:/qwerty/qwertyui/xyz
D:/qwerty/zxc/zxc1/zxcv12/zx/xyz
```

The code:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_to_main_search = 'D:\\'):
    if 'xyz' in dirpath:
      filenames = [fn for fn in filenames if fnmatch.fnmatch(fn, pattern)]
```

Comment: do you want to check D:/qwerty/qwertyui/xyz for other things after finding D:/qwer/xyz ?

Comment: yes, I want to continue search in D:/qwerty/ . For and example,  even if there were /qwerty/qwertyui2, and /qwerty/qwertyui3 i need to go there too. If 'xyz' are in /qwerty/qwertyui2 I want to find it too, but don't need to go to D:/qwerty/qwertyui/new/xyz

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all directory names other than `'xyz'` from `dirnames` in-place so that they will not be traversed:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_to_main_search):
    if 'xyz' in dirnames:
        dirnames[:] = ['xyz']
    if os.path.basename(dirpath) == 'xyz':
        # process filenames
```

Excerpt from `os.walk`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place
>   (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
>   to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes `walk()` again.